Quick Settings menu Icons huge after after upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04.1
I upgraded from LTS 22.04. Everything seems to run fine. I expect the quick settings in the upper right corner to look like this:

But on my system the icons look broken like this:

I tried this: I installed
apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager

then started it and installed "Quick Settings Tweaker" which has some interesting extra settings, but no luck there either.
Then I reset al dconf settings with
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/

but that didn't help either and it was no good idea! Everything was reset to default even language settings, screen resolution, etc.!
How do I fix this?

It looks like there may be text under this screen filling picture.

it is transparent, which is ok, but everything is HUGE. it looks all broken

It seems like not all packages were installed on upgrade. This solves the issue:
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^


log out and in again.

